# Is it possible to use the dancing lights trick?

Tags: scripts, hacking

On Windows, you can make a Visual Basic script to make your keyboard lights blink, but is this possible on Ubuntu? Furthermore, would I be able to hack all my hardware?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/setleds.1.html?

Comment: I doubt you even need  a script. The keyboards lights turn on/off with a keypress on your system? Like Fn+F4 and Fn+F3? If so: see the command `xev`.

Comment: Did I also mention my function keys are locked to certain tasks?

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/437486/how-to-turn-on-off-leds-by-terminal